# a===b и a==b в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Решил изучить для себя новый язык. Но возник один вопрос, который меня смущает.
Что за оператор `===` ? Чем он отличается от обычного сравнения `==`?
Это `equals()`?

Answer (score 12):

В [документации](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) указано, что

`===` является оператором сравнения ссылок на объект

`a == b` аналог простого вызова метода `a.equals(b)`